# php - Get the first and last word on an array

Tags: php

Just started coding PHP, could someone point me to the right direction?
I've got:

```
$text = Barcelona, Catalunya, Spain
```

I want to get only the first and last word which should be

OUTPUT: Barcelona, Spain

I tried this, but it gives me the 2 last words:

```
$text = explode(",", $text);
$size = array_slice($text, -2, 2);
$text = implode(",", $size);
```

OUTPUT: Catalunya, Spain

Could someone help please?

Comment: Take a look at `array_pop` and `array_shift`. They return first and last elements from a given array.

Comment: `$text[0] for first and end($text) for last element` or `reset($text) for first element`

Comment: People have replied so promptly, accept the answer that most suits you, but accept...To help others in future  @ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this hope it will help you:

```
$text = "Barcelona, Catalunya, Spain";
$array = explode(",",$text);
$first_word = $array[0];
$last_word  = $array[count($array)-1];

echo $first_word. ', '.$last_word;
```

Output:

```
Barcelona,  Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $array = array(Barcelona, Catalunya, Spain);
   $first = reset($array);
   $last = end($array);

   var_dump($first, $last);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$text` now has the array of values so

first element:

```
$text[0]
```

or

```
reset($text)
```

last element:

```
end($text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) for first element and [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) for last element

```
$text = "Barcelona, Catalunya, Spain";
$exp = explode(", ", $text);

$string = current($exp) . ", " . end($exp);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/bAGc7Qtn)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first and last x elements, you can use `array_slice()` but as you want the gap, simply [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_merge) two slices like this

```
function createCenteredGap($gapLength, $text) {
    $length = (strlen($text) - $gapLength) / 2;
    $gapLength = 1;
    return array_merge(
        array_slice($text, 0, $length),
        array_slice($text, $length+$gapLength, $length)
    );
}
```

This will do the trick when called like `createCenteredGap(1, $text)` as you can see in [this demo](http://codepad.org/RGyM9DQ3)

Comment: @ryan will also work for larger lists ad gaps, but I would suggest that you check before the function if the explode worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this very simple regexp

```
preg_match('/^(.[^,]*)\s*,.*,\s*(.*)$/', $text, $match);
$first = $match[1];
$last = $match[2];
```

If you are sure that elements are only words without digits and other symbols you can modify this regexp